# Split a string of a specific pattern into three parts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am given a string which is of this pattern:

```
[blah blah blah] [more blah] some text
```

I want to split the string into three parts: `blah blah blah`, `more blah` and `some text`.

A crude way to do it is to use `mystr.split('] ')`, and then removes the lead `[` from the first two elements. Is there a better and performant way (need to do this for thousands of strings very quickly).

Comment: is the first set of `[blah blah blah]` and the second set `[more blah]` always going to contain the same amount of characters?

Comment: @TehTris, not really. They will contain content of varied lengths.

Comment: Then `re` is probably going to be your best bet, unless you want to do a bunch of silly stuff like 
`first = line[:line.find(']')]`
`second = line[len(first):line.find(']')]`
`third = line[len(first)+len(second):]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the text, if you know that it will be in that form. For efficiency, you can precompile the regex and then repeatedly use it when matching.

```
prog = re.compile('\[([^\]]*)\]\s*\[([^\]]*)\]\s*(.*)')

for mystr in string_list:
    result = prog.match(mystr)
    groups = result.groups()
```

If you'd like an explanation on the regex itself, you can get one [using this tool](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2a%29%5C%5D%5Cs%2a%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2a%29%5C%5D%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%29).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wonder if it is possible to use regex to match the similar situation where the second `[more blah]` block may or may not exist. In other words, can we use a regex to split strings which are either `[blah blah] [more blah] some text` or `[blah blah] some text`?

Comment: @skyork: Yep, just add an 'optional' (`?`) modifier to a non-capturing group `(?: ... )` which encloses the second set of `[]`. In other words, this: `\[([^\]]*)\]\s*(?:\[([^\]]*)\])?\s*(.*)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to split where you want to leave out characters:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '[...] [...] ...'
>>> re.split(r'\[|\] *\[?', s)[1:]
['...', '...', '...']
```