# split or chunk dynamic string into specific parts and merging in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there way to split or chunk the dynamic string into fixed size? let me explain:

Suppose:

```
name = Natalie
Family = David12 

length = len(name)  #7 bit
length = len(Family) # 7 bit
```

i want to split the name and family into and merging as  :

```
result=nadatavilid1e2
```

and again split and extract the the 2 string as

```
x= Natalie
y= david
```

another Example:

```
Name = john
Family= mark
```

split and merging:

```
result= jomahnrk
```

and again split and extract the the 2 string as

```
x=john 
y= mark
```

.

Remember variable name and family have different size length every time not static! . i hope my question is clear. i have seen some related solution about it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701536/split-a-string-of-a-specific-pattern-into-three-parts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914554/split-string-into-n-parts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205079/split-a-string-into-parts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749701/python-split-string-into-smaller-chunks-and-assign-a-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749195/how-can-i-split-and-parse-a-string-in-python) but none of these work with what im looking for. Any suggestion ??  Thanks

i'm using spyder python 3.6.4

I have try this code split data into two parts:

```
def split(data):
    indices = list(int(x) for x in data[-1:])
    data = data[:-1]
    rv = []
    for i in indices[::-1]:
        rv.append(data[-i:])
        data=data[:-i]
    rv.append(data)
    return rv[::-1]

data='Natalie'
x,c=split(str(data))
print (x)
print (c)
```

Comment: where is the code you have trie so far and what didnt work with it

Comment: i have try with this code split into 2 parts but its not working what im looking for code is there : def split(data):
    indices = list(int(x) for x in data[-1:])
    data = data[:-1]
    rv = []
    for i in indices[::-1]:
        rv.append(data[-i:])
        data=data[:-i]
    rv.append(data)
    return rv[::-1]

data='natalie'
x,c=split(str(data))
print x
print c

Comment: @natalie could you [edit] your post to include that in  a code block please - comments really aren't any good for code...

Comment: what i want is data it self every time split into 2 bit as long as the length of the string and merging with other string in between as shown in the example

Comment: ok sorry, i will edit it

Comment: @natalie how do you expect to go back from `result=NaDatavilid` to `x= Natalie
y= david`? The `e` is missing from `result`. Do you want to store it from the previous operation?

Comment: Also how come when davids as assigned to `y` it now has a `.` at the end

Comment: yes sorry i miss write the e yes its should be there

Comment: What would be the expected output when one name is significantly longer then the other, how would you expect to split them back into two names?

Comment: Is there some constraint here that names will be equal length or differ by no more than 1? otherwise how can a function know how to split back in 2 names

Comment: @Chris Doyle yes both string are equal length,

Comment: @Chris Doyle the both variable name and family are equal in length size for sure.what you said its absolutely right, that's why i mention both string equal length size

Comment: you first example uses Natalie(7chars) and David(5 chars) if both are equal length then this becomes a trivially easy pproblem to solve

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, sir , i give two example with different string length size, but if name is 7 bit the family will be 7 bit also and so one , i hope you got my point sir

Comment: but  you have given exmaple name = Natalie Family = David here name and family are not the same length

Comment: @ChrisDoyle my god, i'm sorry its my mistake , i will edit the code, the both variable should be same length , sorry sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have stated names will always be of equal length you could use wrap to split in to 2 char pairs and the zip and chain to join them up. In the split part you can again use wwrap to split in 2 char pairs but if the number of pairs is odd then you need to split the last pair into 2 single entries. something like.

```py
from textwrap import wrap
from itertools import chain


def merge_names(name, family):
    name_split = wrap(name, 2)
    family_split = wrap(family, 2)
    return "".join(chain(*zip(name_split, family_split)))


def split_names(merged_name):
    names = ["", ""]
    char_pairs = wrap(merged_name, 2)
    if len(char_pairs) % 2:
        char_pairs.append(char_pairs[-1][1])
        char_pairs[-2] = char_pairs[-2][0]
    for index, chars in enumerate(char_pairs):
        pos = 1 if index % 2 else 0
        names[pos] += chars
    return names

print(merge_names("john", "mark"))
print(split_names("jomahnrk"))
print(merge_names("stephen", "natalie"))
print(split_names("stnaeptaheline"))
print(merge_names("Natalie", "David12"))
print(split_names("NaDatavilid1e2"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
jomahnrk
['john', 'mark']
stnaeptaheline
['stephen', 'natalie']
NaDatavilid1e2
['Natalie', 'David12']
```

Comment: prefect and supper answer, god bless you always. this is what i'm looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
a = "Eleonora"
b = "James"

l = max(len(a), len(b))
a = a.lower() + " " * (l-len(a)) 
b = b.lower() + " " * (l-len(b))

n = 2
a = [a[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]
b = [b[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(b), n)]

ans = "".join(map(lambda xy: "".join(xy), zip(a, b))).replace(" ", "")
```

Giving for this example:

```
eljaeomenosra
```

Comment: From the examples (even though one is slightly off - might be a typo...) the OP has given... it looks like pairs of letters are needed from each, so given your example, it seems they'd want it to be `ElJaeome...`

Comment: @CedricDruck good answer thx, but u are split the strings into one bit look to the anser ejlaemoensora

Comment: The second part seems impossible. When merging the two names, by definition you lose the individual lengths. If you allow using the original lengths then it may be possible

Comment: but your answer for first part was wrong sir, as i seen u split only one bit and merging another bit compare both answer of mine and yours in your code

Comment: You could also do something like: `ans = ''.join(''.join(names) for names in zip_longest(*[re.findall('.{,2}', name) for name in (a, b)], fillvalue=''))` which'll scale to more than one name and you can specify the order... can't see how you'd get back to 2 names, let alone more, but seems to work...

Comment: colude u modify your code plz sir, im getting NameError: name 'zip_longest' is not defined

Comment: @natalie make sure you `import re` and `from itertools import zip_longest` at the top of your file

Comment: @CedricDruck thanks for your code sir its help my first part, hopefully i solve second part.

Comment: @CedricDruck if we try split the result  into two parts as the both a and b are equal length size? what you suggest in this case?